# not able to call http_get function my MySql

Tags: mysql, http-get

I have written stored procedure for calling URL using http_get function but getting error that http_get not exist

```
  DELIMITER $$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Demo`()
    BEGIN
    SELECT http_get('abc.com/aa') ;

    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: is there any way to call URL directly from MySql

Comment: No thank god MySQL isn't a webbrowser and it would be really terrible for security

Comment: can't we achieve it using UDF. I can write CLR function in SQL Server that can call webservice directly from SQL server, can we achieve this in MySql

Comment: Sure you can do it with a UDF. You can also write a UDF to `rm -rf /var/lib/mysql`. That doesn't mean it's a good idea! Please, just consume web services from your application code. Don't do it in SQL.